# elisp: read file into list of lists

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to read a file contents into a two-dimensional list, split by newlines and spaces. For example,

```
a b
c d
```

needs to become

```
(list (list "a" "b") (list "c" "d"))
```

Currently I only know how to read the contents into a simple list determined by newlines. Whenever I need to use an element from that list, I have to split it by spaces everytime, but preferably this should be done only once beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
(with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo")
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (split-string x " " t))
          (split-string
           (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))
           "\n")))
```

Answer (score 4):

While abo-abo's answer above is fine, it creates a temporary string with the full contents of the file, which is inefficient.  If the file is very large, it is better to walk a buffer collecting data line-by-line:

```
(defun file-to-matrix (filename)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filename)
    (let ((list '()))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (let ((beg (point)))
          (move-end-of-line nil)
          (push (split-string (buffer-substring beg (point)) " ") list)
          (forward-char)))
      (nreverse list))))
```

Note the use of `with-temp-buffer`, which avoids leaving a buffer lying around, and the use of `insert-file-contents`, which avoids interfering with any other buffer that might be visiting the same file.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, but it can be shortened. For the string splitting part, use `(split-string (thing-at-point 'line t))` instead and thereby get rid of the inner `let`, the `beg` variable, and the `move-end-of-line` call. Need to change `forward-char` to `forward-line` for this as well.

Comment: @SteveVinoski you're right, although I usually prefer to avoid depending on the rather complex `thing-at-point` library.

Answer (score 2):

With [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), [**`s`**](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) and [**`f`**](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) third-party libraries:

```
(--map (s-split " " it) (s-lines (s-chomp (f-read "FILE.TXT"))))
```

or:

```
(->> "FILE.TXT" f-read s-chomp s-lines (--map (s-split " " it)))
```

which are the same thing.