# How to read contents of the file programmatically in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to read config.json file inside .emacs, how can I do this?

```
(require 'json)
(setq config (json-read-from-string (read-file "config.json")))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simplify your code to:

```el
(defun my-file-contents (filename)
  "Return the contents of FILENAME."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filename)
    (buffer-string)))
```

edit: Although in this particular instance, I see that `json-read-file` is already defined, which cuts out the middle man.

Emacs 24.5 defines it like so:

```el
(defun json-read-file (file)
  "Read the first JSON object contained in FILE and return it."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (json-read)))
```

Answer (score 3):

For JSON just use `json-read-file`. For general files [**`f`**](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) library provides [`f-read-bytes`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-read-bytes-path) and [`f-read-text`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-read-text-path-optional-coding):

```
(f-read-text "file.txt" 'utf-8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this code:

```
(defun read-file (filename)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((new (get-buffer-create filename)) (current (current-buffer)))
      (switch-to-buffer new)
      (insert-file-contents filename)
      (mark-whole-buffer)
      (let ((contents (buffer-substring (mark) (point))))
        (kill-buffer new)
        (switch-to-buffer current)
        contents))))
```

Answer (score 1):

For those you dislike writing quite so much code you can use `f-read` from the `f` library (not part of the standard library). This comes from this question: [elisp: read file into list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043763/elisp-read-file-into-list-of-lists)